# Perform Fetched based on ID in IOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to code a method that performs a fetch based on the ID(NSInteger value) I have passed in. I can form a fetch of everything, but when I add the predicate, the program crashes. Have I done the predicate wrong.

```
-(BOOL)finding:(NSInteger)theID 
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %i",theID];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Course"    inManagedObjectContext:_cdStack.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setHavingPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_cdStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}
```

Comment: replace `self` with the property name of the entity

Comment: What crash are you seeing? Although, @samfisher is right that the `self` in the predicate should be the property name instead. That is likely what's causing the crash.

Comment: I changed self to id, which is the property in the Course entity. Now I get an error saying *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid fetch request: HAVING with no GROUP BY'. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, but I just ran into the same error mentioned in the followup discussion. So just in case if someone else ends up with the same issue, the problem is using `[fetchRequest setHavingPredicate: predicate];` instead of `[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];`.